Flutter Bluetooth Low Energy device not reading characterics data
How can i read characteristic data from a bluetooth low energy device using the flutter_reactive_ble package.
This is the error am currently getting
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: GenericFailure<CharacteristicValueUpdateError>(code: CharacteristicValueUpdateError.unknown, message: "GATT exception from MAC address FF:24:01:06:20:E4, with type BleGattOperation{description='CHARACTERISTIC_READ'}")

Here are the functions am currently running
First I get the device information
  getDevice() {
    Uuid u1 = Uuid.parse('00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb');
    Uuid u2 = Uuid.parse('00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb');
    Uuid u3 = Uuid.parse('0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb');

    flutterReactiveBle.scanForDevices(withServices: [u1, u2, u3], scanMode: ScanMode.lowLatency).listen((device) {
      setState(() {
        name = device.name;
        id = device.id;
      });
    });
  }

The get device function works well and am able to retrieve the device information successfully.
Then I connect to the device
  connectToDevice() {
    Uuid ser = Uuid.parse('0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb');
    Uuid cha = Uuid.parse('00000001-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb');

    flutterReactiveBle.connectToDevice(
      id: id,
      servicesWithCharacteristicsToDiscover: {ser: [cha]},
      connectionTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 10),
    ).listen((connectionState) {
      setState(() {
        able = connectionState.connectionState.name;
      });
    }); 
  }

The connect device function also works well I am able to connect to the device successfully.
Then to read a characteristic
  readFromDevice() async {
    Uuid ser = Uuid.parse('0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb');
    Uuid cha = Uuid.parse('0000fff1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb');
    
    final characteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(serviceId: ser, characteristicId: cha, deviceId: id);

    final response = await flutterReactiveBle.readCharacteristic(characteristic).then((value) {
      print(value.toString());
    });
    
    print(response.toString());
    
  }

This is the function that throws the error am trying to get the device time
Here is a note from the device documentation
Characteristic UUID：0xFFF2 (properties：write，APP send command to Device)
Characteristic UUID：0xFFF1 (properties：Notify，Device send data to AP)
and to read meter time it says
Acquire meter time 0x01
Not sure how to read this any help will be greatly appreciated.

The Characteristic 0xFFF1 does not allow reading since it does not have the "read" property:

Characteristic UUID：0xFFF1 (properties：Notify，Device send data to AP)

To get the informations you need to subscribe to the notifications of this characteristic. The flutter_reactive_ble documentation contains this code snippet:
final characteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(serviceId: serviceUuid, characteristicId: characteristicUuid, deviceId: foundDeviceId);
   flutterReactiveBle.subscribeToCharacteristic(characteristic).listen((data) {
      // code to handle incoming data
    }, onError: (dynamic error) {
      // code to handle errors
    });

My guess would be that you won't receive anything there unless you send a command via the 0xFFF2 characteristic first. But the correct procedure should be part of your documentation

Thanks alot @michael-kotzjan but how can I set the my app for the meter time characteristics the documentation says to use 0x01 to acquire meter time but the format I can use with the plugin is in this format 0000fff1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb where and how does the 0x01 come in

Could it be that you need to send 0x01 to the 0xFFF2 characteristic so that you receive the time via notification on the 0xFFF1 characteristic? You can use a generic BLE exploration tool such as nRF Connect to test this

ok thanks will check the exploration tool out and revert back
